# Visual Studio Code Not staging changes TFVC

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc

Visual Studio Code is not staging any changes made to the code. It seems to change the file and save it after '<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>'. 

I connected to my TFS Server Workspace and set my user settings for `tfvc.location` to `TF.exe` file. I had to set my `tfvc.restrictWorkspace` to true as well. 

How do I setup visual studio code to stage my changes so I can commit them to my Visual team server?

Comment: Is your workspace type "local" or "server"? I suspect you may need to switch it to "local".

Comment: It should be server if its not on my machine right? its an on premise TFS 2015.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. A local workspace does automatic detection of changed files. A server workspace requires explicit check out/in to notify the server of pending changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a short list of steps to get up-and-running with TFVC support, you may check whether your setting is correct:

- Install the Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code.
- Team Foundation Server requires your domain credentials.
- Ensure you have a TF command line client installed.
- Set the **tfvc.location** VS Code setting to the full path of your TF
  command line client.

  Open **File -> Preferences -> Settings**, and add the following lines to your **user settings**:

  If you have VS 2015 installed on your machine, your path to Team Foundation tool (tf.exe) may look like this:

`{
    "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
}`

Or for VS 2017:

`{
    "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\tf.exe",
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
}`

- Open a folder containing a **Local** TFVC Workspace and sign in when
  prompted. From **View -> Command Pallette** ..., type **team signin**, Provide **user name --> Enter -->** Provide **password** to connect to TFS
- Set the SCM Provider to TFVC.

Detailed step you can refer to the documentation below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start

Also, you could check the video below which shows you how to set up the TFVC support on Windows and demonstrates much of the functionality available for Team Foundation Version Control. The features shown in this video apply equally well to the TFVC support on macOS and Linux:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I used the youtube video you referenced as my guide to setup my IDE. I'm just not able to stage file changes. If you watch the video he shows 4 changes to commit. I don't get that. All mine does is show a clock in blue at the bottom right of source control icon. then it changes the file without staging.

Comment: Do you use local workspace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=vsts?

Comment: Yes it was set to server. I want it set to server, but i switched to local and did a test and it worked. It might be an issue with locking files to one user.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio sometimes it's just forgetting to click "Go Online" after new branch creation or some connections issues.
So check:
Solution Explorer -> Solution -> Go Online